# how to write single query for multiple joins in SQL Server 2008(Sample Query Given)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I need to have below join repeated for multiple students. How can optimize and write it as a single query?

```
select * from percentage perct
join subject subj ON perct.subject_id=subj.subject_id
join student std ON subj.student_id = std.sutdent_id
Where std.student_name="xyz" and std.location="abc" and age="18"

select * from percentage perct
join subject subj ON perct.subject_id=subj.subject_id
join student std ON subj.student_id = std.sutdent_id
Where std.student_name="ccc" and std.location="kkk" and age="19"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from percentage perct
join subject subj ON perct.subject_id=subj.subject_id
join student std ON subj.student_id = std.sutdent_id
Where (std.student_name="xyz" and std.location="abc" and age="18")
or (std.student_name="ccc" and std.location="kkk" and age="19")
```

Comment: can't i write something below in sqlserver? this below query is possible in mysql.SELECT  *
FROM    percentage perct
JOIN    subject subj
ON      subj.subject_id = perct.subject_id
JOIN    student std
ON      std.student_id = subj.student_id
WHERE   (std.student_name, std.location, age) IN (('xyz', 'abc', 18), ('ccc', 'kkk', 19))

Comment: WHERE (std.student_name, std.location, age) IN (('xyz', 'abc', 18), ('ccc', 'kkk', 19))  - is this not possible in sqlserver?

Comment: That syntax is not valid in sql server.  You can do this though:
std.student_name in ('name1','name2')
and std.location in ('abc','kkk')
and age in ('18','19')